# How to disable block production log for nodeos?

Tags: nodeos, log

I am running several docker images, one of them is EOSIO blockchain. The block production log it produces fills the terminal. I don't want to see it, the logs of other containers are much more important, and not the blockchain's logs.

I don't want to detach from all containers, and docker-compose does let you detach from only one container.

I tried to redirect the logs into a file. But there comes another problem. When I stop the container with Ctrl+C, the next time I run, I got 'database dirty flag set' which means abnormal exit. I can add '--hard-replay', but it's not the right way, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new documentation explains [how logging works in nodeos](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/logging/index).

You have to create a `logging.json` file in the `config_dir` for nodeos.

I believe (although I haven't tested it), that you can disable logging with:

```
{
  "name": "consoleout",
  "type": "console",
  "args": {
    "stream": "std_out",
  },
  "enabled": false
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Actually, I have solved my problem with [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini), after reading [this](https://kkc.github.io/2018/06/06/gracefully-shutdown-docker-container/) post. And that way I'm redirecting logs, so I save them.